# Bootbox confirm: return client result in order to do postback to rowCommand

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview, bootbox

Before bootbox, I did this on aspx file in gridview;

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" CssClass="btn btn-danger" OnClientClick="if(!confirmDelete()) return false;" runat="server" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="DeleteRow" Text="Delete"/>
```

and on js file;

```
function confirmDelete() {
return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the record?"); }
```

And with confirmation, the gridview's RowCommand is triggered and the deletion is done.

With bootbox, I am realy stuck. I know bootbox is asynchronus and try to use 'preventDefault', but it didn't work. So how can I convert the above js file to bootbox version?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally come up with this solution;

```
function confirmDelete(sender) {
    if ($(sender).attr("confirmed") == "true") {return true;}

    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?", function (confirmed) {
        if (confirmed) {
            $(sender).attr("confirmed", confirmed).trigger("click");
        }
    });

return false;
}
```

And changing button's OnClientClick;

```
OnClientClick="return confirmDelete(this);"
```

Answer (score 5):

I've tried [Fatih Bilginer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4176989/fatih-bilginer/) solution, but it requires another click to do postback, so I changed `.trigger("click")` for `sender.click();`

`EDIT`

```
function confirmDelete(sender) {
    if ($(sender).attr("confirmed") == "true") {return true;}

    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?", function (confirmed) {
        if (confirmed) {
            $(sender).attr('confirmed', confirmed);
            sender.click();
        }
    });

return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've doing a some change in [dannyzar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6006227/dannyzar) code, I used `callback:` to call function

and I've added some design to bootbox modal

```
function confirmDelete(sender) {
          if ($(sender).attr("confirmed") == "true") { return true; }

          bootbox.confirm({
          message: "Are you sure you want to delete?",
          buttons: {
              confirm: {
                  label: 'Yes',
                  className: 'btn btn-success'
              },
              cancel: {
                  label: 'No',
                  className: 'btn btn-danger'
              }
          }
          ,callback: function (confirmed) {
              if (confirmed) {
                  $(sender).attr('confirmed', confirmed);
                  sender.click();
              }
          }});

          return false;
      }
```